# Native Callback function to Async.waterfall

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, bluebird

I'm implementing a project written in Node.js and getting values from Mysql.
As I get deeper in my project my nested callback like this

```
hold.getEntry(function(data){
    var ref = data.ref;
    var id = data.id;
    var message = data.mess;
    var json = JSON.parse(message);

    if(ref === null){
    } else {
        hold.checkPositionCandidate(ref, id, json, function(dataa){
            console.log("checker " + dataa);
            if(dataa == false){
            } else {
                //\/ here I get error callback is not a function
                hold.getVoterCount(id, json, function(votercount){
                    if(votercount.count == 0){
                    } else {
                        checkVoter(ref, votercount.count, function(isallcorrect){
                            if(isallcorrect == false){
                                console.log('mali votes');
                            } else {
                                console.log('tama votes');
                            }
                        })
                    }
                });
            }

        });
    }
});
```

and I get "callback is not a function". I have researched and found out about 'callback hell' so I found an alternative and use Async.js

now my problem is how i will convert this code into async.waterfall???
can someone help me with this???? pleaseeee.

**UPDATE 1**

I have implemented Peteb's answer but, when I execute it onlu execute the first function. Here is the new code.

```
var id = "";
var json = "";

async.waterfall([
    function (callback) {
        // hold.checkPositionCandidate
        // if err return callback(err, null)
        // if successful return callback(null, dataa)
        hold.getEntry(function(data){
            var ref = data.ref;
            id = data.id;
            var message = data.mess;
            json = JSON.parse(message);

            callback({'ref':ref, 'id':id, 'json':json});
        console.log(data);
        });
    },
    function (dataa, callback) {
        // hold.getVoterCount
        // if err return callback(err, null)
        // if successful return callback(null, votercount)
        if(dataa.ref === null){
            callback(null);
        }else{
            hold.checkPositionCandidate(dataa.ref, dataa.id, dataa.json, function(dataaa){
                callback(dataaa);
            });
        }
        console.log('gfh');
    },
    function(anoData, callback) {
        // checkVoter
        // if err return callback(err, null)
        // if successful return callback()
        if(anoData === false){
        } else {
            hold.getVoterCount(id, json, function(votercount){
                if(votercount == 0){
                } else {
                    console.log('last function');
                }
            });
        }
    }
], function (err, results) {
   // When finished execute this
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async.waterfall` flattens your nested callbacks and passes results from one function to the next in the order defined using a single [error-first callback](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/). So each step in your callback chain will represent your waterfall functions in the order they need to execute.

```
async.waterfall([
  function (callback) {
    // hold.checkPositionCandidate
    // if err return callback(err, null)
    // if successful return callback(null, dataa)
  }),
  function (dataa, callback) {
    // hold.getVoterCount
    // if err return callback(err, null)
    // if successful return callback(null, votercount)
  }),
  function(votercount, callback) {
    // checkVoter
    // if err return callback(err, null)
    // if successful return callback()
  })
], function (err, results) {
   // When finished execute this
});
```

---

**EDIT:** Updated answer to address the updated question.

`callback({'ref':ref, 'id':id, 'json':json}); // this is wrong`

[`async.waterfall()`](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/README.md#waterfall) is expecting that the first param of your callback as either an `Error` or `null`. Any values that need to be passed, go after the `Error` parameter.

```
// this is correct
return callback(null, { ref: ref, id: id, json: json }); 

// this is also correct
return callback(null, ref, id, json);
```

**Example `hold.getEntry()`**

```
hold.getEntry(function(data){
  var ref = data.ref; 
  id = data.id;
  var message = data.mess;
  json = JSON.parse(message);

  return callback(null, {ref: ref, id: id, json: json});
});
```

Comment: thankyou for your response. i'll give you an update about your example.

Comment: i apllied you sample in my project but it only execute the first function

Comment: You need to replace my comments with your actual logic for those functions and call the callback function when execution has completed so the next function can be called.

Comment: yes, I already did that sir. BTW I posted the my improved codes

Comment: @something you're not implementing your callback correctly. You need to use error-first callbacks. That is how async structures their callbacks as do most things in Node.

Comment: it's working now! thankyou! one last question. how do I stop the chain of function if the first function returns a null value?

Comment: it will automatically send it to the `async.waterfall()` callback function that you pass in to the second argument when calling waterfall.